# SharePoint: how to update a SPListItemVersion's property

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish - to change a draft's property, which through the OM appear as read-only. Is there a way or my search is futile and I'll end up deleting and creating another item?

Thanks in advance!

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/sites/blank2"))
        {
            foreach (SPListItemVersion v in site.RootWeb.Lists["Pages"].Items[0].Versions)
            {
                if (v.Level == SPFileLevel.Draft)
                {
                    // CHANGE PROPERTY HERE
                    // NOT POSSIBLE TO DO e.g., v["Title"] = "blah", it's read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the SPListItemVersion object only has Get properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion_properties.aspx